# Request sql COUNT not return to zero

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery

There is problem in my request to find news on my site so I had the problem when I count the occurrences of quote_plus_normal_publi, the problem is that this statement of COUNT resumes the addition of all results of the main query so I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
SELECT date, mess, publi, profil, color, name, search,

(SELECT COUNT(quote_plus_normal_publi.id_post_normal)
FROM publi
INNER JOIN quote_plus_normal_publi
ON publi.abo_id = quote_plus_normal_publi.abo_id
WHERE publi.id_personnes = 1) AS plus

FROM publi
WHERE id_personnes = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
```

OUTOUT :

>

```
 name:     John, SIr
> 
> search:    $jhon, $sir
> 
> color:    5, 15
> 
> profil:    null, null
> 
> publi:    null, null
> 
> mess:    "HEY", "HI"
> 
> date:    1535427143, 1535627143
> 
> plus:    4, 4
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: Your sub-query needs to be _correlated_, i.d. add a condition for the outer publi table.

Comment: sorry i'am using postgres

Comment: How i can do that ?

Comment: Step 1) Have different table aliases for the two publi instances.

Comment: Step 2) Put a condition in the sub-query referencing the main query's publi table alias.

Comment: i try and i say you if it's work

Comment: SELECT date, mess, id, publi, profil, color, name, search,



(SELECT COUNT(quote_plus_normal_publi.id_post_normal)
FROM publi
INNER JOIN quote_plus_normal_publi
ON publi.abo_id = quote_plus_normal_publi.abo_id
WHERE publi.id = id) AS plus

FROM publi
WHERE id_personnes = 1
ORDER BY date DESC


i got error like column "id_pub" does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating the `publi` table in the subquery -- and it is in the outer query.

I doubt this is what you intend.  You want to connect the subquery to the outer query using a *correlation* clause:

```
SELECT p.*,  -- or whatever columns  you want
       (SELECT COUNT(qpnp.id_post_normal)
        FROM quote_plus_normal_publi qpnp
        WHERE p.abo_id = qpnp.abo_id
       ) as plus
FROM publi p
WHERE p.id_personnes = 1
ORDER BY p.date DESC;
```